How to change from readonly to not readonly of input in ASP.NET Core
MODAL
<div class="modal fade" id="residentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="residentModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="residentModalLabel">Resident Details</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container mt-5">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    <label for="modalResidentID">Resident ID:</label>
                                    <input for="modalResidentID" type="text" id="modalResidentID" class="form-control" readonly>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                               
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    <label for="modalFirstName" >First Name:</label>
                                    <input for="modalFirstName"  type="text" id="modalFirstName" class="form-control" readonly>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    <label for="modalMiddleName">Middle Name:</label>
                                    <input for="modalMiddleName" type="text" id="modalMiddleName" class="form-control" readonly>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
                                        <label for="modalLastName">Last Name:</label>
                                        <input for="modalLastName" type="text" id="modalLastName" class="form-control" readonly>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    <label for="modalBirthdate">Birthdate:</label>
                                    <input for="modalBirthdate" id="modalBirthdate" class="form-control" type="date" readonly />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    <label for="modalAge">Age:</label>
                                    <input for="modalAge" id="modalAge" class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    <label for="modalEmail">Email:</label>
                                    <input for="modalEmail" id="modalEmail" class="form-control" type="email" readonly />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
     
                <!-- Addresses -->
                <h5>Addresses</h5>
                <div id="modalAddresses"></div>
                <h5>Contacts</h5>
                <div id="modalContacts"></div>

                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="modifyCheckbox">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="modifyCheckbox">
                        Modify Information
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

resident.js

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var modifyCheckbox = document.getElementById('modifyCheckbox');
    var inputsToModify = document.querySelectorAll('input:not([type="checkbox"]), select, #modalAddresses input, #modalContacts input');

    function toggleFieldsReadOnly() {
        var isReadOnly = !modifyCheckbox.checked;
        inputsToModify.forEach(function (input) {
            // Disable age field explicitly
            if (input.id !== 'modalAge') {
                input.readOnly = isReadOnly;
            }
        });
    }

    // Toggle fields on page load
    toggleFieldsReadOnly();

    // Toggle fields when checkbox state changes
    modifyCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
        toggleFieldsReadOnly();
    });
});

// Additional script to ensure dynamically generated inputs in addresses and contacts are handled
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#residentModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var resident = button.data('resident');

        $('.view-resident-btn').click(function () {
            var residentData = $(this).data('resident');

            // Set resident information
            $('#modalResidentID').val(residentData.ResidentID);
            $('#modalFirstName').val(residentData.FirstName);
            $('#modalMiddleName').val(residentData.MiddleName);
            $('#modalLastName').val(residentData.LastName);
            $('#modalBirthdate').val(residentData.Birthdate);
            $('#modalAge').val(residentData.Age);
            $('#modalEmail').val(residentData.Email);

            // Handle addresses
            var addresses = residentData.Addresses || [];
            var addressInputs = $('#modalAddresses');
            addressInputs.empty(); // Clear previous address inputs
            addresses.forEach(function (address, index) {
                // Create input fields for each address
                var addressInput = '<div class="row">'
                addressInput += '<div class="address-group col-md-3 mb-3">';
                addressInput += '<label for="addressType' + index + '">Address Type:</label>';
                addressInput += '<input id="addressType' + index + '" class="form-control" type="text" value="' + address.AddressType + '" readonly>';
                addressInput += '</div>';
                addressInput += '<div class="address-group col-md-3 mb-3">';
                addressInput += '<label for="houseNumber' + index + '">House Number:</label>';
                addressInput += '<input id="houseNumber' + index + '" class="form-control" type="text" value="' + address.HouseNumber + '" readonly>';
                addressInput += '</div>';
                addressInput += '<div class="address-group col-md-3 mb-3">';
                addressInput += '<label for="street' + index + '">Street:</label>';
                addressInput += '<input id="street' + index + '" class="form-control" type="text" value="' + address.Street + '" readonly>';
                addressInput += '</div>';
                addressInput += '<div class="address-group col-md-3 mb-3">';
                addressInput += '<label for="barangay' + index + '">Barangay:</label>';
                addressInput += '<input id="barangay' + index + '" class="form-control" type="text" value="' + address.Barangay + '" readonly>';
                addressInput += '</div>';
                addressInput += '</div>';
                addressInputs.append(addressInput);
            });

            // Handle contacts
            var contacts = residentData.Contacts || [];
            var contactList = $('#modalContacts');
            contactList.empty(); // Clear previous contact inputs
            contacts.forEach(function (contact, index) {
                // Create input fields for each contact
                var contactInput = '<div class="row">'
                contactInput += '<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">';
                contactInput += '<label for="contactType' + index + '">Contact Type:</label>';
                contactInput += '<input id="contactType' + index + '" class="form-control" type="text" value="' + contact.ContactType + '" readonly>';
                contactInput += '</div>';
                contactInput += '<div class="address-group col-md-6 mb-3">';
                contactInput += '<label for="contactNumber' + index + '">Contact Number:</label>';
                contactInput += '<input id="contactNumber' + index + '" class="form-control" type="text" value="' + contact.ContactNumber + '" readonly>';
                contactInput += '</div>';
                contactInput += '</div>';
                contactList.append(contactInput);
            });

            // Update read-only status based on checkbox state
            toggleFieldsReadOnly();
        });
    });
});



I want to achieve on this when the resident clicks the checkbox to modify the all the details my problem on this only resident information change to not read only but the address and contact didn't change. Based on the screenshot provided only the resident information change to not red only but for the contacts and address still read only

You are trying to get the <input> elements under the #modalAddresses and #modalContacts <div> elements and stored in the inputsToModify (global) variable before the elements are rendered.
Move the inputsToModify variable in the toggleFieldsReadOnly scope. This ensures that the .querySelectorAll() works as getting those elements after they are rendered.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var modifyCheckbox = document.getElementById('modifyCheckbox');

  function toggleFieldsReadOnly() {
    var inputsToModify = document.querySelectorAll(
      'input:not([type="checkbox"]), select, #modalAddresses input, #modalContacts input'
    );

    var isReadOnly = !modifyCheckbox.checked;
    inputsToModify.forEach(function (input) {
      // Disable age field explicitly
      if (input.id !== 'modalAge') {
        input.readOnly = isReadOnly;
      }
    });
  }

  ...
});

Demo @ StackBlitz
